# (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream. nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

I configured my EC2 server about 3 weeks ago and had Nginx installed for reverse proxy and HTTPS. I then had an elastic IP attached to it. I shut down to save cost. Today I restarted my EC2 and finding it difficult to connect to my EC2.

My app is a node app (backend code). When I go to my URL it returns an error, "Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later."

On my error log for Nginx, I see the following

*`*48 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ---my ip---, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/auditions HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/ap..."`*

I have also confirmed that NGINx is running and my security groups are just as I had set them three weeks ago.

I'm not quite sure if I missed a step but does rebooting your EC2 instance change things around?

Comment: I think you need to start your node app. It is the upstream NGINX can't connect to.

Comment: I can verify that I started and restarted it again. pm2 status says that it's running

Comment: Does anything change with `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/auditions`?

Comment: can you elaborate more how are you accessing it and post the settings for security groups? also did you configure any iptable reroute?